# Using mysql pool with async\await | nodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, connection-pooling, mysql2

I am using mysql2 with nodejs and currently using simple connection like the following:

mysql.ts

```
    const Connect = () => {
  if (!connection)
    return mysql.createConnection(params);
  return connection;
};
```

someQuery.ts

```
 const connection = Connect();
    const asyncQuery = util.promisify(connection.query).bind(connection);
```

Now, after a while that the server is running the app just crashes because of the connection loss, I read some online and understood that in order to solve it and also as a better practice I should use a connection pool.
The thing is that I haven't really found anything that works like the above with async-await.

Does anyone have a solution for this?
await asyncQuery('query here');

Answer (score 0):

i had a project last year, where i used the mysql2/promise library.

connector.js

```
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

const con = mysql.createPool({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        password: "pw",
        database: "database",
        waitForConnections: true,
        connectionLimit: 10,
        queueLimit: 0

});

module.exports = con;
```

queries.js

```
const db = require('../helpers/mysql/connector');

getAnything: async () => {
                try {
                        let anything = await db.execute("SELECT * FROM anything");
                        return colos[0];
                } catch (e) {
                        console.log(e);
                        return null;
                }
        },
```

Comment: Hi,
Could you please share how you query though? this is just the connection creation.